# Boost + Visual Studio 2010 + Windows Platform SDK 7.1

Tags: windows, visual-c++, boost

Could someone tell me a command line switch for bjam or something else that will make boost compile with VS2010 using the new Windows Platform SDK 7.1 toolchain?  It's an option you can set in a normal visual studio project.  The default is v100 a variant of the platform 7.0 toolchain.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: IIRC Windows SDK 7.1 uses the same C++ compiler and CRT that ships with VS 2010, so just building from VS 2010 command prompt should suffice.

Comment: No by default VS 2010 uses what's called v100 which is a variant of 7.0a I'm pretty sure.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay just found this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2010/04/07/coming-soon-win-sdk-for-windows-7-and-net-4.aspx Which says VS2010 does use an up to date version of the headers but dosen't specifically say 7.1. It does say in most cases there is no need to switch. I would still like to know how to acomplish this even though it may make no difference. Thanks.

Comment: Basically the toolset is the same in both VS 2010 and WSDK 7.1 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2010/04/01/windows-sdk-build-environment-upcoming-features-and-improvements.aspx). Besides that, what platform specific headers are you worried about that could affect boost?

Comment: Actually, try just opening the "Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt" instead of the "Visual Studio Command Prompt" and then proceed as I specified below.

Comment: Just curious -- what's the striking difference between SDK 7.1 and VS2010's version?

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your environment

```
set SdkTools=c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin 

call "%SdkTools%\SetEnv.Cmd" /xp /x86
```

assuming that's where you have the Windows SDK installed.  Info is from [here](http://lists.boost.org/boost-build/2007/03/16265.php) - there may be more to do, but this looks on the right track to me.

Answer (score 0):

To build boost 1.43.0 libraries for VS 2010:

- Download and extract to C:\Temp\boost_1_43_0
- Start Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt
- [Build BJam](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/jam/building.html)

`cd C:\Temp\boost_1_43_0\tools\jam\src`

`build.bat`

- [Build Boost](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html) using BJam

`cd C:\Temp\boost_1_43_0`

`tools\jam\src\bin.ntx86\bjam.exe --with-regex link=static runtime-link=static threading=multi variant=debug,release address-model=32,64`

- Check bin.v2 or stage/lib for output. Note [naming conventions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming).

May need to build in two phases with just `address-model=32` then with just `address-model=64`. In this case we are choosing to build libs that statically link to the C runtime and to statically link to the boost lib itself.

Use `--with` to build non-header based libs like regex. Note stage/lib will be overwritten after each address-model build, but all libs are always kept in bin.v2.

Comment: Just noticed boost 1.44 is out. I specified boost 1.43 because that's what I built using the above not too long ago.

Comment: Thanks for the general info on boost and Visual Studio but that is not quite what I was asking.  I was asking specifically how to make bjam use Windows Platform SDK 7.1 toolchain as the default is v100 a variant of Platform SDK 7.0a.  Thanks.