# Trying to install boost libraries, not working?

Tags: c++, boost

I download the file where it says 'download now' from:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/

when i unzip, there's a small .exe file. I run this (and also as administrator) a command prompt pops up and disappears  instantly.

Yet everywhere i read i should be getting licence agreement etc.

Im on Win 7 64?

Help :)

Answer (score 1):

That's just the [boost jam](http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/jam/index.html) build tool. You probably want the [complete](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.44.0/boost_1_44_0.zip/download) boost source archive. Then to build it, say for VS 2010, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706466/boost-visual-studio-2010-windows-platform-sdk-7-1/3706740#3706740).

Comment: it always annoys me when they cant just put all this in the installer, i know how to code, i dont know how to mess around with configurations. really puts me off using extra libraries :)

Comment: cd jam source location .\build.bat i seem to be getting stuck on the above, i dont have a bat file, just an exe

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/jam/building.html

Comment: I just download 1.44 now. Extracted and built bjam from `\tools\jam\src` using `build.bat`.

Comment: I just successfully built boost 1.44 using bjam. It seems you still have to build the 32-bit and 64-bit targets separately, i.e. do not specify `address-model=32,64`, use two separate builds passing `address-model=32` to the first commandline and `address-model=64` to the second (including all the other commandline options you want).

Answer (score 0):

Open `cmd.exe` as an administrator, then run the .exe.  That way, you can see the output.

Answer (score 0):

Use [one of the installers](http://www.boostpro.com/download/) provided by BoostPro computing. It is going to be much easier for you.